# Then method not fired after Promise.resolve()

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In Ionic2, I am trying to design a javascript method that will open a modal webview, let user enter some data, and then a callback should be fired when the modal webview is closed.

I am trying to achieve this using Promise.

This is the plan:

```
var openWebviewPromise:any;

this.openWebview(path).then(()=>{
  //this line after then is never fired!
  console.log("do something when webview is closed");
});

openWebview = (path:string) => {
  // do something to listen to webview closed even
  this.openWebviewPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // open the modal webview here.
  });
  return this.openWebviewPromise;
}

// Then I listen to event when the modal iframe is closed manually by user, I tried to call .resolve when that happens, hoping then() will be called.
window.addEventListener('message', this.formCloseEventHandler);

formCloseEventHandler = (event:any) =>{
  if(event.data == "embed-auto-close-popup"){
    if(this.openWebviewPromise !== undefined){
      this.openWebviewPromise.resolve();
    }
  }
}
```

It didn't work. when modal is closed, we fire this.openWebviewPromise.resolve(), but the then line is not triggered.

Comment: Do you not call `resolve()` inside the anonymous function?

Comment: In this particular code `this.openWebview` and `openWebview` are (should be) two different things…!?

Comment: `this.openWebviewPromise.resolve` should not exist/shouldn't be a function. You can't `resolve` a promise from without.

Comment: Ah I see.... so I cant resolve it outside, when an event happens...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be writing

```
openWebview(path:string) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    … // open the modal webview here.
    … // do something to listen to webview closed even and call resolve()

    // Listen *here* to event when the modal iframe is closed manually by user
    window.addEventListener('message', (event:any) => {
      if (event.data == "embed-auto-close-popup") {
        resolve(); // or reject(new Error(…));
      }
    });
  });
}
```